# android.database.staledataexception : Access closed cursor

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am using a custom listview in my activity and trrying to populate it with values. But, I am getting this "staledataexception", which i dont undersdtand why....

Here is the code, the error occurs on the line tagged as "error here"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upadtemailservr);

        headText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        prefsPrivate = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PRIVATE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Heading = prefsPrivate.getString(KEY_PRIVATE, "the string not found");
        headText.setText("Update Mail Server - "+Heading);

        AddNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        AddNew.setOnClickListener(this);


         m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        //the first tried one... this was not working... so i tried the one writtten next to it.
        /*
         m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
         this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
         this.setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
            */      

        //new list adapter

        MainList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainlist1);


           viewOrders = new Runnable()
           {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getOrders();
            }
           };
             Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
                thread.start();
                m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateMailServr.this,    
                      "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

                m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this,R.layout.row,m_orders);
               MainList.setAdapter(m_adapter);
               MainList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }  

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable(){

         @Override
            public void run() {
                if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
                    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                    m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
                }
                m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    };



           public void getOrders() {
               m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

               adapter1 = new DBAdaptertrial2(this);
            adapter1.open();
            Cursor cur1 = adapter1.fetchAllMeetings();

            cur1.moveToFirst();
            for(int i=0;i<cur1.getCount();i++)
            {
                         //******Error here**************
                if(Heading.equalsIgnoreCase(cur1.getString(1)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(!cur1.getString(5).equals(""))
                        {
                            Order o1 = new Order();
                            o1.setMailserver(cur1.getString(5));
                            o1.setPriority(cur1.getInt(8));
                            o1.setIpaddr(cur1.getString(2));
                            m_orders.add(o1);
                        }
                        if(!cur1.getString(6).equals(""))
                        {
                            Order o2 = new Order();
                            o2.setMailserver(cur1.getString(6));
                            o2.setPriority(cur1.getInt(8));
                            o2.setIpaddr(cur1.getString(2));
                            m_orders.add(o2);
                        }
                        if(!cur1.getString(7).equals(""))
                        {
                            Order o3 = new Order();
                            o3.setMailserver(cur1.getString(6));
                            o3.setPriority(cur1.getInt(8));
                            o3.setIpaddr(cur1.getString(2));
                            m_orders.add(o3);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
                    }
                  runOnUiThread(returnRes);

                }
                else
                {
                    cur1.moveToNext();
                }   
                cur1.close();
            adapter1.close();


            }

    }       

           @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

               viewOrders = new Runnable()
               {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    getOrders();
                }
               };
                 Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
                    thread.start();
                    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateMailServr.this,    
                          "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

           }  

        // End of all the list stuff
```

Comment: you should be using a CursorAdapter, and avoid starting threads in an activity.

Comment: ok.. let me just try it out.. i'll get back again

Comment: Hi... can you please guide me how to use the CursorAdapter for this, My doubt is is i assign the cursor some values from the database then how do i use it to put the data to the ArrayList and then use it in the Listadapter.

Comment: the point of using a cursoradapter is to avoid using a arrayadapter. cursor adapters are more powerful since they don't require all data to be available at once. see examples here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be getting the cursors using managedQuery.

I had problems with restoring an application, which for some reason in Icecream Sandwich did not close the cursors properly. The fix was to do this for all cursors right after using them:

```
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
  myActivity.stopManagingCursor( cursor );
  cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: ICS isn't managing the cursor for you because start/stopManagingCursor was deprecated in API 11. A better strategy is to use a LoaderManager. It also has the benefit of loading the cursor on a background thread, making your app a little more responsive.