# Application crashes onResume in ICS while working perfect on Gingerbread

Tags: android, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My main Activity (say A) raises intent to fetch a ContactID from ContactsContract through

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, contactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),PICK_CONTACT);
```

While returning (onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data)), I am using details from 'data' to query the contacts through

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        ......
```

my code works fine with Android 2.x. However this code gets crashed in ICS (Android 4.x), while resuming the main Activity(A).
I am not sure, whether it is due to the deprecated 'managedQuery'.
Can somebody offer some solution, I am stuck and unable to even find which line causes the error as the Log cat is not showing even the error line number. it simply says 
 **Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.** 
Thanks in advance
Joshy

I have tried the above code just after completing the requirement of the cursor. Still the problem persists. My Log cat says as follows

```
08-13 00:26:31.427: W/dalvikvm(3176): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.desquare.sp/com.desquare.sp.SmartPadActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176): Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:75)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:144)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4505)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-13 00:26:31.447: E/AndroidRuntime(3176):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, along with the specific methods of your code referenced in that stack trace, pointing out which lines of your code are the specific lines mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: I have placed my entire stacktrace above. Please see that none of my methods are mentioned. Except the name of my main Activity (SmartPadActivity). @Raghav

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like this is the problem:

> *
>   [android.database.staledataexception : Access closed cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330495/android-database-staledataexception-access-closed-cursor)
>
> You seem to be getting the cursors using managedQuery.
>
> I had problems with restoring an application, which for some reason in
>   Icecream Sandwich did not close the cursors properly. The fix was to
>   do this for all cursors right after using them:

```
if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {  
  myActivity.stopManagingCursor( cursor );   
  cursor.close(); 
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code just after completing the requirement of the cursor. Still the problem persists. My Log cat says as follows

Comment: OK: Q: are you using startManagingCursor()" anywhere (deprecated at version 2.2)?  Explicitly calling "cursor.close()" anywhere?  Look here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23746

Comment: Dear Paulsm4, Thank you very much for your help. I have commented the cursor.close() call after all managedQuery. Now my app is back on wheels in both Gingerbread and ICS. Thanks for you help once again

Comment: I am facing same issue, please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589345/staledataexception-attempted-to-access-a-cursor-after-it-has-been-closed

Answer (score 0):

The API startManagingCursor/stopManagingCursor is deprecated and is the root cause of the issue.
For example, please comment this out and verify.