# StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, cursor, fatal-error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lenovo.phone, PID: 4885
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:3514)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1500)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use a local database object that will solve your issue

Comment: First thing that I haven't downvoted it but the possible reason for downvote is you have only posted your code and haven't explain anything related to it like what you are trying to achieve and what progress have you made etc.

Comment: @VivekMishra most probably that is the reason for downvote and also as exception in pretty descriptive to solve the issue

Comment: @ankitagrawal yes but according to the general format this question lacks description

Comment: yeah in that you can ask OP to update the question to clarify, and not downvote the question, this question is valid

Comment: The stacktrace says you have activity-managed cursors so the problem is what you do with your cursors on the caller level.

Comment: are you calling readfrom_db() from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
protected SQLiteDatabase database;
```

and make it local

Basically 2 method are executing concurrently and one method called `database.close()` and 2nd method is still accessing data so the `Exception`

use this:

```
public class db {

DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
Context mContext;


public db(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public db open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    return this;
}


public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public void insertdb( int id,String ph_num, String call_type, String calldate, String call_duration, String upload_status) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.id,id);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.phone_number, ph_num);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.call_type, call_type);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.call_date, calldate);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.call_duration, call_duration);
    values.put(DataBaseHelper.upload_status, upload_status);
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.table_name, null, values);
    database.close();
    // Log.d("Database helper", "values inserted");
}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM call_logtable";
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("phone_number", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("call_type", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("call_date", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("call_duration", cursor.getString(4));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close(); // just added
    database.close();
    return wordList;
}

/**
 * Compose JSON out of SQLite records
 * @return
 */
public String composeJSONfromSQLite(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM call_logtable where upload_status = '"+"no"+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("phone_number", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("call_type", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("call_date", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("call_duration", cursor.getString(4));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close(); // just added
    database.close();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
    return gson.toJson(wordList);
}


public int dbSyncCount(){
    int count = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM call_logtable where upload_status = '"+"no"+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close(); // just added
    database.close();
    return count;
}


public void updateSyncStatus(String id, String status){
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String updateQuery = "Update call_logtable set upload_status = '"+ status +"' where id="+"'"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query", updateQuery);
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();
}

public Cursor getinformation()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DataBaseHelper.phone_number,DataBaseHelper.call_type,DataBaseHelper.call_date,DataBaseHelper.call_duration,DataBaseHelper.upload_status};
    return database.query(DataBaseHelper.table_name,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public void delete()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // String[] columns={DataBaseHelper.phone_number,DataBaseHelper.call_type,DataBaseHelper.call_date,DataBaseHelper.call_duration};
    database.delete(DataBaseHelper.table_name, null, null);
}


StringBuffer readSpecificfrom_db(String type)
{
    String ph_number=null;
    String call_type=null;
    String call_date=null;
    String call_duration=null;
    String upload_status=null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    //sb.append("Call Log :");
    Cursor cursor_object=getinformation();
    cursor_object.moveToFirst();
    do {
        if((cursor_object.getString(1)).equals(type)) {
            ph_number = cursor_object.getString(0);
            call_type = cursor_object.getString(1);
            call_date = cursor_object.getString(2);
            call_duration = cursor_object.getString(3);
            if(type=="Missed") {
                sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + ph_number +
                                " \nCall Type:--- " + call_type +
                                " \nCall Date:--- " + call_date
                        //   + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + call_duration
                );
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + ph_number +
                        " \nCall Type:--- " + call_type +
                        " \nCall Date:--- " + call_date
                        + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + call_duration);
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }while(cursor_object.moveToNext());
    cursor_object.close(); // just added
    return sb;

}

StringBuffer readfrom_db()
{
    String ph_number=null;
    String call_type=null;
    String call_date=null;
    String call_duration=null;
    String upload_status;
    //  int id=0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    // sb.append("Call Log :");
    Cursor cursor_object=getinformation();
    cursor_object.moveToFirst();
    do {
        ph_number=cursor_object.getString(0);
        call_type=cursor_object.getString(1);
        call_date=cursor_object.getString(2);
        call_duration=cursor_object.getString(3);
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + ph_number +
                " \nCall Type:--- " + call_type +
                " \nCall Date:--- " + call_date
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + call_duration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");

    } while(cursor_object.moveToNext());
    cursor_object.close(); // just added
    return sb;
}
```

}

Comment: you are creating dbhelper many times just make it one time and reuse and only keep database local

Comment: and also you are not calling cursor.close() you should also call cursor.close() everytime you are done with your cursor

Comment: u didn't answered which line no in my code you are getting exception?

Comment: I removed the comments I posted above, yeah post it, so I will accept :) and I suggest you to delete your comments too... otherwise people will think this was planned to reward you

Answer (score 0):

You should not close the gotten readable/writable database manually. It will be closed by the your dbHelper when you close it and will manage the synchronization with other open/close operations that could cause those exceptions.

Comment: If you are calling asynchronously to your methods, remove all the `database.close()` lines. Since `getReadable/WritableDatabase()` will return allways the same instance (if you have not closed it), if you call `getXDatabase()` from 2 places and close it from one of them, you are closing it in the other place and your cursors will be invalidated. Not sure if it is your case.